# Opa bootstrap samples

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, opa

I'm trying to make Twitter's Bootstrap API (http://bootstrap.opalang.org/) work in Opa by trying some features, and there is one that refuse to work : the WB.grid system. More precisely, the parser report a syntax error when I try to do that :

```
    grid_basic = (WBootstrap.Grid.row([
        {span=8 offset=none content=<>foo</>},
        {span=8 offset=none content=<>bar</>}
        ]))
```

(that is, a simple row with two cells)

Here's the error string :

```
            grid_basic = (WBootstrap.Grid.row([
                    {-->span=8 offset=none content=<>foo</>},
                    {span=8 offset=none content=<>bar</>}
                    ]))

            Hint: File "test1.opa", line 9, characters 4-10, (9:4-9:10 | 158-164),
            found a binding as condition. Did you mean `==' rather than `=' ?
```

After a while I just copy pasted the whole code of a sample page (http://bootstrap.opalang.org/html/src/container_app.opa.html), and it failed on the "grid" line too. 
I tried both the new and old parser. Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bootstrap.opalang.org is written with and for the old syntax.

Moreover, it uses Bootstrap 1.4.0 widgets, wich are outdated (stdlib.widgets.deprecated.bootstrap).

So you can use `opa --parser classic`, or transform the code into js-like syntax : `{name1:value1, name2:value2, ...etc...}` (see [manual](http://doc.opalang.org/manual))

Comment: What is the latest version of Bootstrap for Opa, then ?

Comment: Nevermind, checked the API. I guess there isn't up-to-date samples anywhere, then ?

Comment: I don't think the Opa wrapper of bootstrap is up-to-date. I just use bootstrap the "old-fashioned" way with Opa, and that's what I'd recommend. The old-fashioned way is to include the bootstrap css in your opa project, then make use of bootstrap classes the way you would in ordinary html.

Comment: The update version og WBootstrap is here : http://doc.opalang.org/module/stdlib.widgets.bootstrap/WBootstrap. It should work with `import stdlib.themes.bootstrap`

Comment: More info : http://lists.owasp.org/pipermail/opa/2012-March/000916.html and https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/issues/43

Comment: Ok, thanks. I finally managed to implement the sample, but now I'm having an issue with the dropbown lists (namely, they don't drop down). I guess it must come from a confusion between the packages or something, I'll look into that.

Comment: If you want to use dropdown effect, you have to include Bootstrap JS which is not embeded in the stdlib. You have to import the js yourself : http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html